# Can I capture an old PC's printer output with an Arduino and post the data to S3?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have an old medical device that has no data export- it only prints data via serial port to an old dot matrix printer. I would love to build a small embedded device that logs the serial output as a text file and would automatically transfer the file to an Amazon S3 bucket. These files are big- probably more than 1 or 2 megabytes.

Ideally, the device is idiot-proof and requires no user operation- just sits there recording the printer output and saves it somewhere.

The medical device computer is Windows NT and I don't want to mess with writing software for Windows NT- I just want a simple device that can record the printer output and save it- ideally wirelessly.

Is this possible with an Arduino with a WiFi board and probably some onboard Compact Flash storage? If you can think of an easier/better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: I love this question, but I have a feeling it is going to lead to some subjective discussion.

Comment: Please no. Not subjective! NOoooooooo!!!! I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: HAHA, just letting you know about how I felt, as there may be others that feel this same way and may try to close your question.  There is a proposal for an [Arduino Stack Exchange Site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino).  You should post this question there to see if it helps their cause.

Comment: I think that is only beta(area 51) and not taking questions, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ethernet Shield has a micro SD card.

For a quick solution: You can have function that stores your data to a file. And then have a ethernet object serve up the file, upon WGETs. see [Adafruit's Ethernet examples](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/ethfiles.html)

For a more sophisticated solution see [Webduino](http://code.google.com/p/webduino/)

or [mysql client](https://launchpad.net/mysql-arduino)

Comment: Many thanks @mpgflaga. I'm reading those ethernet examples now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the serial line from another PC? There are many hardware converters that will make a serial line readable from a USB port.

Is it the case that you are looking at an Arduino because it is initially easier to program than a Windows application?  If so, search the web for keyword "MSDN" plus whatever topic you are interested about as it pertains to Windows.

That is, currently, Microsoft's MSDN web site has lots of good technical information that would help to develop a Windows application that does what you want an Arduino to do.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jack- I was only trying to make a less cluttered environment without having to worry about reboots and the like. I thought a computer would probably be easier to program but an embedded device would be more idiot-proof. Maybe.